# North Carolina Code question for splicing 6x6 posts

Tags: code-compliance, deck, engineering, splicing

I have a 48 X 10 second floor deck with 6X6 posts.  I want to add a roof above about half of it.  It is not feasible to replace the 6X6's with longer ones as I would basically end up replacing the deck, and it just wouldn't be a safe process.

I am also not sure about the minimum/maximum distance from deck boards that this should be done.  Obviously the lower the better for looks purposes.

Does anyone know if this is defined in North Carolina code?  I have checked around and it seems like the acceptable method is a 24" rabbet sandwiched between galvanized plates, through bolted.

Anyone else have any knowledge of this as it relates to North Carolina code, or am I getting an engineer?